# Why is Flask program running twice, with double object instantiation (no Debug Mode)?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, flask-socketio, eventlet

I'm basing my app on the [Flask-MQTT example](https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT/blob/master/example/app.py) and it's generally working fine, except that when I run the program it runs twice and creates two instances of the MQTT client class.

Of course I set "*use_reloader*" to "False". The background process (and the rest of the code after "*if **name** == '**main**':*") only runs once. It seems like the only thing being doubled is the MQTT client, which proceeds to connect twice from two separate instances. Then it subscribes twice, and gets every message twice. No bueno.

Is there a good way to make sure the program is only being run once (I assume the "*mqtt = Mqtt(app)*" line is being run twice), or at least prevent two clients from being created?

[image of heroku logs showing double client connection (and two workers?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsdky.png)

```
import eventlet

from flask import Flask, render_template, current_app
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt, MQTT_LOG_ERR
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

eventlet.monkey_patch()

import json
from flask_cors import CORS
from threading import Lock
import os
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import message_handler
import ui_data
import background_processes

load_dotenv(verbose=True)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
app.config['SECRET'] = 'my secret key'
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = os.environ.get('CLOUDMQTT_URL')
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('CLOUDMQTT_USERNAME')
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('CLOUDMQTT_PW')
app.config['MQTT_CLIENT_ID'] = ''
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 20
app.config['MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION'] = True

app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = int(os.environ.get('CLOUDMQTT_SSL_PORT'))
app.config['MQTT_TLS_CA_CERTS'] = 'ca.crt'

mqtt = Mqtt(app, mqtt_logging=False)

CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', engineio_logger=False, logger=False)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


socket_background_thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()


def update_ui(app):
    last_update_data = None
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            socketio.sleep(10)
            update_data = ui_data.get_update_data()
            if last_update_data is not None and update_data != last_update_data:
                data = dict(
                    payload=update_data
                )
                socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)
                socketio.sleep(0)
            last_update_data = update_data


@socketio.on('connect')
def start_notifications_thread():
    global socket_background_thread
    with thread_lock:
        if socket_background_thread is None:
            socket_background_thread = socketio.start_background_task(update_ui, current_app._get_current_object())


@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    topic = 'test'
    mqtt.subscribe(topic)


@mqtt.on_disconnect()
def handle_disconnect():
    print(f"MQTT - disconnecting ")
    pass


def process_message(message):
    message_text = message.payload.decode()
    message_time = time.time()
    message_handler.parse_and_handle_message(message_text, message_time)
    socketio.sleep()

   
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    message_text = message.payload.decode()
    print(f'received message: {message_text}')
    background_thread = socketio.start_background_task(process_message, message)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    background_process = socketio.start_background_task(background_processes.start_background_threads)

    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))
    host = '0.0.0.0'

    socketio.run(app, host=host, port=port, use_reloader=False, debug=False)
```

Comment: Well, the hack way is to set the MQTT_CLIENT_ID field to something....that way only one connection is allowed using that name.  ...but it doesn't solve the problem of why?

Comment: @JDAllen side issue, but oddly enough, I can set that client ID field to anything, and when I check the _client_id in the on_message it still comes out as an empty string so I put the issue on the back burner.

In any event, despite having no set client ID, the clients don't kick each other off. A surprise, to be sure.